# OpenApi for Python

Tags: python, openapi

I'm trying to use OpenAPI for a Python project.

I've previously used OpenAPI with Java and it was really easy as you could configure it into pom.xml so that you would write a yaml file and then you would get an interface that you could implement into your controller.

I'm now working in Python and I'm trying to do a similar thing where you write an yaml file and get an interface or something similar that you can use.

I've tried **openapi-generator-cli generate** but it seems like it creates a lot of bloat files as it creates the whole server but I only need a single file that I can use further.

Is there something similar for Python as it is for Java?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [`import flask_restx`](https://pypi.org/project/flask-restx).

Then visit top-level URL of your flask app to see the swagger details.

https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/swagger.html#swaggerui

EDIT

Consider using [apispec](https://apispec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html).

```
$ pip install -U 'apispec[yaml]'
```

Comment: Wouldn't this create a swagger documentation for an API? I want to get the API from a yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

can try flask-toolkits [link](https://pypi.org/project/flask-toolkits/) very easy to setup as it will generate your openapi/swagger spec. Once you already done your code can try with `app.run()` then access http://localhost:5000/openapi.yaml